# SharePoint 2013 ribbon doesn't look right

Tags: 2013, ribbon, browsers

You ever have one of those problems where your google-fu doesn't work because you have no idea what words to use? That's the problem I have with two of my SharePoint 2013 sites. Simply put, the ribbon looks like this:

[image]

But on my other site, it looks like this (as it should):

[image]

This behavior is only happening in Google Chrome, with IE 11 it looks fine. I have IE 10 at work, and I THINK it was misbehaving there as well.

So what did I do, and how do I undo it?

Comment: The ribbon usually does that when it's being squeezed. Do you have your resolution low, browser window small, or have any custom css/masterpage?

Comment: OK, now I feel like an idiot. I had zoom at 90% in Chrome. Once I changed it back to 100%, it went back to normal. For some reason, two sites had zoom at something other than 100%, and another one was at 100%, so I thought it was site-specific, when it was browser tab-specific. Mike, you put me on the right road, please submit as an answer so I can give you +1 Internets for the day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This view is usually because the browser window is being squeezed. If you have your resolution low or browser window small, it can do that. Also if you have any custom masterpage that sizes down that control that will do it.

Comment: The culprit was Chrome had zoom at 90%. Mike's answer led me to the solution.

Comment: Came across this issue on SharePoint 365 Online. Edge Chromium was zoomed at 90% for me. When set to 100%, the ribbon was back to normal.